# How to access Custom field,which is defined in Construction feature package- Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

By reading my question, you might think its very easy, but i request everyone to try to access a custom field defined in the construction feature package.

I want to access "Type" field in Project screen's Task Tab in details

[image]

UsrType is a custom field defined in Construction features package. In that package, file has been converted into dll. I tried to access that field like we usually do in customization.

[image]

but i got error

> Type or Namespace "PMTaskExt" could not be found

I even tried this

[image]

I got error

> UsrType Doesn't exist in PMTask

There is also same problem with UsrSubcontractNbr field in APTran. Not Only these fields, there are many such field to be accessed.
How can we access such fields?

Comment: you would use GetExtension but you need the correct namespace. Not sure where in the customization properties that would show but maybe if you look at the DAC extension for that it will indicate the namespace. Looking at the Construction feature package might also indicate the namespace to use.

Comment: PX.Objects.PM.PMTaskExt ext = PXCache<PMTask>.GetExtension<PX.Objects.PM.PMTaskExt>(pmTaskNewEntry);      It didnt work Brendan.

Comment: I would assume that is not the namespace. Would need to look at the PX.Objects.CN.dll to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at PX.Objects.CN.dll it would be in the `PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions` namespace as `PmTaskExt`

Used the latest 19R2 Construction project "ConstructionFeatures_19_205_4_1_157"

Decompiled the customization dll (used DotPeek) I searched for PMTask:

[image]

Copied text:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.Descriptor;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.PM;

namespace PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions
{
  public sealed class PmTaskExt : PXCacheExtension<PMTask>
  {
    [PXDBString(30)]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Required = true)]
    [ProjectTaskType.List]
    public string UsrType { get; set; }

    public static bool IsActive()
    {
      return PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.construction>();
    }

    public abstract class usrType : BqlType<IBqlString, string>.Field<PmTaskExt.usrType>
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Something like this should work:

```
var cnExt = PXCache<PX.Objects.PM.PMTask>.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions.PmTaskExt>((PX.Objects.PM.PMTask)e.Row);
```

Do note the .Net version of PX.Objects.CN.dll is using 4.8 in case that causes any issues with version compatibility in visual studio if your solution is compiled on the same version of Acumatica for 19R2 which is 4.7.1

Comment: I used  this "var cnExt = PXCache<PX.Objects.PM.PMTask>.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions.PmTaskExt>((PX.Objects.PM.PMTask)e.Row);"   but it says "ProjectAccounting doesnt exist in the namespace". when I dcompile dll in Dotpeeks, I don't see the project Accounting class.

Comment: I used DotPeek to decompile the PmTaskExt class. What version of the construction edition are you using?

Comment: I am using  Acumatica 2019 R1    Build 19.104.0024 
 ConstructionFeatures19.104.3199 and PX.Object,CN is refering .netversion 4.0

Comment: Hey Brendan. I resolved that PX.Object.CN.dll issue. I just took that dll from 19.205 version and imported into 19.104.0024. That worked for me. but i got new error here saying "Error: An incorrect type of extension has been requested."  I have tried in two ways but did not work.

Comment: I am using like this PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions.PmTaskExt cnExt = PXCache<PX.Objects.PM.PMTask>.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions.PmTaskExt>(pmTaskNewEntry);
PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions.PmTaskExt cnExt = projectEntryGraph.Caches[typeof(PMTask)].GetExtension<PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting.PM.CacheExtensions.PmTaskExt>(pmTaskNewEntry);